# pkg file extracting instead of installing?

Tags: install, pkg

Recently I noticed my pkg updates are being extracted rather than installed. (for example the MS Office update wanted to extract the file)

Is there a way to ensure that pkg files are installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most obvious cause would be that some other app has taken over the .pkg extension - maybe a file compression utility.

Find any .pkg file &  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>i</kbd>  to Get Info.
Where it says Open with, select Installer, then Change All

[image]